# Insert into local table from remote exec stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I've tried this:

```
insert into MyTable (col1, col2... coln)
exec remoteServer.remoteDB.dbo.StoredProcedure.

The operation could not be performed because the OLE DB provider 'SQLOLEDB' was unable to begin a distributed transaction.
```

Local server is SQL 2000, remote is 2008.

Any idea?
When I try executing the stored procedure things run smoothly, I get the result `SELECT` So the problem is at copying.

I've tried enabling MSDTC and it's configuration (as seen [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/816701))

Comment: Looked in the windows event logs on both sides?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you've not already tried this, try wrapping this callout within a `DISTRIBUTED TRANSACTION`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188386.aspx

```
BEGIN DISTRIBUTED TRAN

...

COMMIT TRANSACTION
```